# Dynamic class instance on Laravel relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to use one table for multiple classes in a Laravel relation.
So i.e. I have a user, a user can have skills. 
The only difference between skills is the logic they have so they are defined as different classes. 
I would like to not add a special table for them as they only have to exist in the logic.

Is there a way in Laravel to let a relation check a column to find it's class?

This is the code on the owner so to say in this case a user.

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        public function skills()
        {
            return $this->morphMany(Skill::class, 'owner');
        }

        public function learnSkill($className)
        {
            $this->skills()->create(['type' => $className]);
        }

    }
```

This is the abstract class I would like to define a skill in.

```
    abstract class Skill extends Model
    {

    }
```

These are the classes I would like to get from the relation as they can have different logic.

```
    class PHP extends Skill
    {

    }

    class HTML extends Skill
    {

    }
```

Current problem is that we ask Laravel to instantiate 'skill' what of course is not possible because it is abstract and it should be. 
Laravel throws an Exception "Cannot instantiate abstract class App\Skills\Skill".
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships.php

```
    /**
     * Create a new model instance for a related model.
     *
     * @param  string  $class
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function newRelatedInstance($class)
    {
        return tap(new $class, function ($instance) {
            if (! $instance->getConnectionName()) {
                $instance->setConnection($this->connection);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to not define the parent class (Skill) as abstract and overwrite the newFromBuilder method from the model. If anyone has a better solution I'm still looking.

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
{
    $instance = new $attributes->type;

    $instance->exists = true;
    $instance->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

    return $instance;
}
```